# Hat ein als /z​ɑː/ ausgesprochenes langes „so“ eine Bedeutung?

Tags: pronunciation

Manche Menschen sprechen „so“ als [z​ɑː] aus. Ich fragte mich immer, ob das regional ist, ob diese Variation etwas Bestimmtes betonen will? (Un)freundlichkeit? Eile? usw.

**Kontext (nur einer von etlichen):**

> Man will die Rechnung. Das merkt sich der Kellner, der zum Tisch kommt und nicht [zoː] sondern
>
> – [z​ɑː]! Einmal Paulaner, einmal ... (*der Kellner rechnet*)
>
> sagt. Der Vokal ist auch manchmal sehr lang.

Comment: Ich kann keine allgemeine Aussage machen, aber für mich ist es eine Art auszudrücken, dass ich etwas fertiggestellt habe. Meist mit einem Gefühl der Zufriedenheit gepaart, im Sinne von: so, dass hätten wir. Smile.

Comment: Was heißt denn „fast als [zaː]“? So kann ich es mir schwer vorstellen; aber ich glaube nicht, daß ich das sage oder von anderen höre.

Comment: Meinst Du vielleicht "tja"?

Comment: @Robert Nein. Ich meine das, was ich schrieb : ) *tja* klingt [tjaː]

Comment: Statt nur der Aussprache wäre es sinnvoll, auch die Verwendung zu beschreiben? Tritt es überall da auf, wo sonst auch *so* stehen kann, ist es unabhängig von Situationen und Gefühlslagen ?

Comment: In dem Kellnerbespiel ist *So!* nur ein Auswurf (*beachtet mich!*) und hat denke ich unabhängig von der Aussprache keine weitere Bedeutung.

Comment: Ich schliesse mich @RalphM.Rickenbach an, ich kenne es auch als "So, das hätten wir"

Comment: Wenn es das von @Ralph M. Rickenbach beschriebene _soo_ ist, was auch zum jetzt hinzugefügten Beispiel passen würde, dann würde das (vielleicht von einzelnen Dialektregionen abgesehen) auf keinen Fall [zaː] ausgesprochen werden; der Vokal ist auf jeden Fall hinten – also allerhöchstens [z​ɑː] –, aber wohl eher halboffen statt offen und zumindest leicht gerundet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manche Deutsche benutzen in ihrem alltäglichen Sprachgebrauch Ausdrücke wie "ähm" oder ähnliches.
In dem Fall des Kellners scheint es mir, als würde der Ausdruck [zaː] in dieser Situation das Herangehen an den Tisch und das Fertigmachen zum Ausgeben der Getränke überbrücken. In dieser Form ist es ein freundliches auf sich Aufmerksam machen. "Passen Sie auf, jetzt kommen die Getränke — Hier das Pils für Sie". Und so weiter.
Es soll dem Gast womöglich die Gelegenheit geben auf das ankommende Getränk zu reagieren.

Zusammenfassend ist diese Ausdrucksweise bestimmter, womöglich lauter und aggressiver, hat aber keine unfreundliche Absicht (zumindest empfinde ich dies hier in NRW nicht so).

Answer (score 1):

Wenn wir hier über den bayerischen Dialekt sprechen, dann hat [za:] zumindest eine zusätzliche Bedeutung, welche ich mal als "Ausdruck von Skepsis und Misfallen" bezeichnen würde.

Als Beispiel: Ein Münchner im Himmel, in der "klassischen" Zeichentrickform, gelesen von Alois Gondrell.

Etwa 2-2.30 Minuten im Film, nach "Bekanntmachung mit der himmlischen Hausordnung". Erst das "Wos iss?", dann, nach der Wiederholung der Regeln, das "so", will meinen "[za:]".

In der Form hat es wohl jeder, der noch des Bayerischen mächtig ist, verwendet. Einschliesslich meinereiner, in meiner längst vergangenen Jugend in Bayern.

Comment: Danke fuers Editieren. Ich habe keine Umlaute auf meiner US Tastatur und kann/konnte mir die Alt-Sequenzen nie merken.